# Replace a file which has a specific ID with another one

Tags: javascript, jsom

I want to replace a file with another one using JSOM, but preserving all other associated fields (like Author and other custom columns in the document library)

How can I select the file I want to replace using the ID field?

For example, when I update a regular List Item, I use

```
this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(the_given_ID);
oListItem.set_item('Title', value);
```

How can I do that for a file?

**I want to replace the file, not to update its content!**

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

By **replace** and not **update** I hope you mean that even the file type changes i.e. `Document1.docx` becomes `Image1.png`. With that assumption there might be a way to get around this problem.

When we upload a document to SharePoint (if we enable the overwrite option) it identifies the file to overwrite by its name. So in your case if we need to replace your file then we first would have to rename it. I couldn't find any API which renames the file (including file extension) in a document library. However you can trick SharePoint by moving the file to the same document library and renaming it (including the file extension). Below is the code.

```
var docLibPath = "<PATH TO DOCUMENT LIBRARY>"; // For e.g. /sites/TestSite/MyDocLib/
var newFileName = "<NEW FILE NAME>"; // For e.g. Image1.png

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
var oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle("<DOCUMENT LIBRARY>");
var oListItem = oList.getItemById("<LIST ITEM ID>");

var oFileObj = oListItem.get_file();
oFileObj.moveTo(docLibPath + "/" + newFileName);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, successHandler),
    Function.createDelegate(this, errorHandler)
);

function successHandler() {
    console.log("Success!");
}

function errorHandler() {
    console.log("ERROR: " + arguments[1].get_message());
}
```

This will rename your file as per value specified in variable `newFileName`. It also preserves the list item ID.

You can then use the [`SP.FileCreationInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj838440.aspx) to upload the new file making sure that the name of the file is same as `newFileName` and setting [`overwrite`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj850817.aspx) property to `true`.

I was able to test the code to rename (or rather move) the file and it worked. After that I tried to upload a new file, from browser UI, and it replaced the old file. But due to lack of time I was not able to test via code the upload mechanism but I think it should work.